# Platform Event messages not receiving for bulk record updates with partial success

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, platform-event, publish-subscribe

I have a Platform Event that gets published in the After Update Trigger when a certain field gets updated in the Account record. I also have subscribed to the channel via LWC. So far it shows below behaviour in the component

1. Event message received when updating the record manually from UI
2. Event messages received when doing bulk update of the records where all the records got successfully updated
3. Event messages **NOT** received when the bulk update of the records is partially successful.

For the **3rd point**, even though for the partially successful records the events are getting published successfully they are not being received in the subscriber component. The CallbackMethods are also not triggered . Why?

Below code

## Account After Update Trigger Method

```
     public static void publishAccountEventfromTrigger(Set<Id> accountIdSet){

        Map<Id, Account> accMap = new Map<Id, Account>([Select Id, name 
                                                          from Account
                                                          where Id IN :accountIdSet);
   
       List<DummyPlatformevent__e> eventsList = new List<DummyPlatformevent__e>();

       for(Id oppid : accMap.keySet()){

              DummyPlatformevent__e event = (DummyPlatformevent__e)DummyPlatformevent__e.sObjectType.newSObject(null, true);
    
              eventsList.add(event);
         }

         SuuccessFailureCallBack cb = new SuuccessFailureCallBack();

         List<Database.SaveResult> results = EventBus.publish(eventsList, cb);

         // Getting published successfully

       }
```

In the LWC subscriber component, getting the below error message

```
    platformEventsUsageMonitor.js:1 Received error from server:  {"id":"17746","successful":false,"channel":"/meta/connect","failure":{"reason":"","httpCode":0,"connectionType":"long-polling","transport":{},"message":{"id":"17746","channel":"/meta/connect","connectionType":"long-polling","clientId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}}}
```

Comment: As a matter of interest, is the PE "publish after commit" or "publish immediately"?

Comment: publish after commit

Comment: For the 3rd point, how do you know the events are being published successfully?

Comment: I can see it under the Usage column of 'High-Volume Platform Event Hourly Publishing Allocation'. I can also see it in the debug logs when I publish and save the results in Database.saveResults

Answer (score 3):

If your platform event have `publish after commit`, this means it will be published only if parenting transaction succeeds.
In case of partial success, parent transaction fails on the failing records (raising exceptions through `.addError()` method or native functionality).

Which means you need to switch to `publish immediately` on platform event definition if you want the platform events to be fired even when you parent transaction fails which triggers the platform events.

However, make sure the event publishing happens before exception raise or inside a catch or finally block

This is the documentation in the help text icon when configuring the platform event:

> Indicates when a platform event message is published in a Lightning Platform transaction.
>
> **Publish After Commit**
>
> to have the event message published only after a transaction commits successfully. With this option, a subscriber receives the event message after the data is committed. If the transaction fails, the event message isn't published.
>
> **Publish Immediately**
>
> to have the event message published when the publish call executes, regardless of whether the transaction succeeds. With this option, a subscriber might receive the event message before the data is committed.

---

(Updates from comments)

If events are published and then rolled back, this is exactly case for `publish after commit`, since if any other unhandled exception happens afterwards, that would rollback the whole transaction including the previously successfully published events.

From the comments, I conclude that 'Publish Immediately' works and solves topic starter's problem, but topic starter prefers another solution. Well, in such case topic starter needs to find the place where exception happens in the transaction, maybe invoked by trigger, flow trigger or some other means. If topic starter has opened Salesforce Support case, they should help to find out where exactly exception happens which rolls back the whole transaction

Comment: I had reached out to Salesforce. They said even though the records that was success got published, they had been rolled back for some reason. Still waiting for them to  give an explanation.

Comment: Just noticed that you assumed it's not published. It IS published. Just not receiving.

Comment: @Brav so it they are published and then rolled back, this is exactly case for `publish after commit`, since if any other unhandled exception happens afterwards, that would rollback the whole transaction including the previously successfully published events.

Comment: @Brav I wonder what happens if you change to `Publish Immediately`, would it solve your issue? If that solves your issue, then we would confirm that the problem is indeed related to `publish after commit`

Comment: I tried with 'Publish Immediately'. The partially successful records have events published and Received as well. However I cannot go with 'Publish Immediately' as I need to publish them only after the records are saved.

Comment: so this means 'Publish Immediately' works and solves your problem, but you prefer another solution. Well, in such case you need to find the place where exception happens in the transaction, maybe invoked by trigger, flow trigger or some other means. If you have opened Salesforce Support case, they should help to find out where exactly exception happens which rolls back the whole transaction.